# Is WSO2 API Manager certified against JDK7 on Suse?

Tags: java, api, wso2, suse

Is WSO2 API Manager certified against Suse EE SP3 and Oracle Java JDK7 ?

http://docs.wso2.org/display/AM160/Installation+Prerequisites

Whatdoes de * means with JDK7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a technical point of view, the WSO2 products should be able to run on Oracle JDK 7. I do not think anyone has especially tested on Suse EE SP3.

As long as it runs on Oracle JDK, the products should work fine.

The `1.7.*` means that any Java 7 update should work. For example: 1.7.51 ->  Java 7 Update 51

However we have faced issues specific to a Java update. For example, there is an issue with Java 7 update 45. You will encounter [JAXP00010001 error](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-2892) after a certain number of requests to API Manager.

I would recommend you to use the latest JDK from Oracle. AFAIK, we haven't encountered any issue with latest JDK.

I hope this helps.

Comment: If I have support on WSO2 AM, am I able to ask the question to WSO to look into Suse SP3 and WSO2 AM, especially running with multiple cores?

Comment: WSO2 supports Oracle JDK and if an OS can run Oracle JDK, there should not be any issue. You may contact WSO2 support, if you encounter any issue with your environment. If you think that the WSO2 AM is not utilizing the hardware properly, WSO2 support can help you to find solutions.